# Access c++'s vector pointer's elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

How can I access the elements of the vector from vector pointer?
In the following code what should be used instead of `cout << v [0];` to print 10?

```
vector <int>* v; // the function parameter
v->push_back (10);
cout << v [0];
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile.

Comment: I have never found a reason to use a pointer to a vector. If you can, find a solution that does not require it.

Comment: @zyx I'm modifying an existing code. There, a pointer to vector is a function parameter. I dont want change the whole code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you actually had a pointer to a vector, the correct way would be this:

```
cout << (*v)[0];
```

But you don't have a pointer to a vector.  You have an uninitialized pointer, and your call to `push_back` is undefined behavior, as would be trying to print an element of this non-existent vector.

Comment: @mrdabd If so, reference instead of pointer will be more appropriate to be used as parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v->at(0)` or `v->operator[](0)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a pointer to a vector in the first place. It's much more reasonable to construct the vector on the stack:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(10);
std::cout << v[0];
```